# Command "generate-votes" is not defined

Tags: 8, drush

I'd like to use `Drush 10.3.6` to generate votes on my development server.

Based on [these instructions for a previous Drush version (8.x)](https://drushreference.com/drush-8x/votingapi/generate-votes/), there is some kind of module/extension for this.

```bash
drush generate-votes
```

However, when I try it, it doesn't work for me. The error message I get is the following one.

> Command "generate-votes" is not defined.

Has this feature been removed or deprecated? Is there any other way I can generate votes from the command line?

Comment: Is that official docs site?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure but I would guess it's not, it seems buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command doesn't come from Drush core but from the [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module. This command simply doesn't exist yet in the currently latest Voting API release: [8.x-3.0-beta2](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/votingapi/-/tree/8.x-3.0-beta2).  See, the directory `/src/Commands` where Drush commands since Drush version 9 get registered now simply isn't there yet.

You need to get the latest [Voting API dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi/releases/8.x-3.x-dev):

```
$ composer require 'drupal/votingapi:3.x-dev@dev'
```

There the `/src/Commands` directory contains a [VotingApiCommands.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/votingapi/-/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Commands/VotingApiCommands.php) file with all the commands in it. The module needs to be enabled to use them, of course.

---

Voting API version 3.0-beta2 only contains the legacy [`votingapi.drush.inc`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/votingapi/-/blob/8.x-3.0-beta2/votingapi.drush.inc) file for Drush commands up to Drush version 8.